# Habit tracker for linux

Tags: linux, time-management, productivity

Is there a habit tracker for GNU/Linux? It should allow the user to manually record whether the habit was performed or failed at a particular time and provide habit strength statistics, so that I knew where I should pay more attention to accomplish my goals. There is [Loop Habit Tracker](https://github.com/iSoron/uhabits), but it is for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Hello there try those i hope i can help you after a long time of waiting.
https://snapcraft.io/good-job - Good Job
https://github.com/nerdypepper/dijo - Dijo

Reference links:
Dijo - https://github.com/NerdyPepper/dijo
Good Job - https://github.com/good-job-app

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/61980)

Comment: Thank you! Both are worth looking into! My observation is that  _Good Job_ expects the user to build the habit in a predetermined time frame, so it ties statistics to that period only. This should be fine for building a habit, but seems complicated for maintaining habits as a part of a daily routine. `dijo` should be good for a `vim` user because of "vim like command mode". This reminds me of the option of tracking habits with [Org Mode](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-your-habits.html), which I would try if I were using GNU Emacs by now!